# angular2 more views for one class

Tags: angular

the user can choose how he wants to see the details: in a list or in a container for example. Both views use the same class (code). How do I solve this? Is there any kind of input field to easily switch between selections. And how do I use two different templates for one class?

Comment: Yeh, just use a different 'component' with a 'list' template and a 'container' template and invoke them conditionally .  Angular2 is a different way of thinking!

Answer (score 2):

There is a plan to allow multiple `@View()` annotations, but it hasn't yet landed and I don't know how it will work.
What about just using `ngIf` to only display specific parts of **one** view?

```html
<section *ngIf="showSection1">
  ...
</section>
<section *ngIf="showSection2"> <!-- or *ngIf="!showSection1" -->
  ...
</section>
```